# Disk Performance Monitoring

Tags: linux, performance, disk, io

I have a physical server with 2 disks, sda and sdb. I want to monitor their I/O and performance. The monitoring element has 3 types: ops, sps, and bps. What are these and which one is better to monitor and give me useful information?

Comment: What would be useful to you?

Comment: somtimes services become slow or response time increase.. i just want to know if these problems happens because of high disk or not...the value these types return are human-readable or its somthing like 85789257394756748 0-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ops = operations per second
- sps = sectors per second
- bps = bytes per second

More information at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent

They each give good information.  Which one is appropriate in your environment will depend on your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use several different ways to do this:

1. As already mentioned install kind of monitoring system to get the
   information via kind of agent.
2. To use directly `iostat` program, store output in log and run this on
   some schedule
3. Use `sar`to keep performance information in logs (on local machine)
4. Pull this information via `snmp` from `snmp agent` installed on the
   machine

Which way you will choose depend of too many factors